# Inverse laplace transform of $\frac{1}{s^3(s-1)}$

Tags: inverse-laplace

I have a problem with this transform. I know that using this theorem (see the theroem) I can get the answer, and i have the resolution. But I don't understand why the put a $-1$ in the integral.

[IMG with the theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghchp.jpg)

After know this they do:

[Transform to integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFvkT.jpg)
I don't know why they put the -1 in that integral.

Answer (score 3):

See that you have to apply the Inverse Laplace of $1/(s^2(s-1))$ and then plug that into the integral. So we have that with partial fractions:

$$\frac{1}{s^2(s-1)}=\frac{1}{s-1}-\frac{1}{s^2}-\frac 1s $$

So, 
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s^2(s-1)}\right ](t) =e^{t}-t-1, \space t>0$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $e^t$ instead of $e^{-t}$?

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Laplace_Table.aspx look at number 2

Comment: Yes, just a typo, I wrote s+1 instead of s-1. Fixed, thank you (probably because I am used to apply laplace in stable systems (negative poles)).

Answer (score 0):

With the theorem we can say
$${\cal L}^{-1}\left(\dfrac{F(s)}{s^3}\right)=\int_0^t\int_0^t\int_0^t{\cal L}^{-1}F(s)\ dt\ dt\ dt$$
then
\begin{align}
{\cal L}^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\frac{1}{s-1}}{s^3}\right)
&= \int_0^t\int_0^t\int_0^t{\cal L}^{-1}\frac{1}{s-1}\ dt\ dt\ dt \\
&= \int_0^t\int_0^t\int_0^t e^t \ dt\ dt\ dt \\
&= \int_0^t\int_0^t e^t\Big|_0^t \ dt\ dt \\
&= \int_0^t\int_0^t e^t-1 \ dt\ dt \\
&= \int_0^t e^t-t\Big|_0^t\ dt \\
&= \int_0^t e^t-t-1\ dt \\
&= e^t-\dfrac12t^2-t\Big|_0^t \\
&= \color{blue}{e^t-\dfrac12t^2-t-1}
\end{align}